# R: How to automatically set the color of different groups in survival plot

Tags: r, plot, key, survival-analysis

I am plotting the survival probability for my dataframe with 8 different groups with this command:

```
fit2<-Surv((time=t2$uptimeDay,event=t2$solved,type='right')~t2$cluster)

plot(fit2,conf.int=F,xlim=c(0, 250),mark.time=c(1,50,100,200),mark=c(1,3,4,2,5,7,6,8,9,10),lwd=1,cex=0.7,lty = 1:11,xlab='Time(days)',ylab='Survival Probability')
```

the cluster here is a number between 1 and 10.

I would like to know how to automatically set the colors of the curves together with an automatic legend using key of the curves.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that I use for Kaplan-Meier curves that is based on `ggplot2`, which will take care of the colors and legends for you.  Regrettably, I've not gotten around to packaging it up in any sensible way.  But you can download the source code from

https://gist.github.com/nutterb/004ade595ec6932a0c29

And some examples on how to use it from

https://gist.github.com/nutterb/fb19644cc18c4e64d12a

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by making this "automatic" and the desire to "use the key of the curves", but perhaps you are asking that the colors of the curves match the legend.

```
png()
  mycols=c("red","blue")
  plot(prio.fit, fill=mycols)
  legend(x="bottomleft", col=mycols, legend=mycols) 
dev.off()
```

[image]

If you want this mated to a dataset and wanted to specify particular colors for your groups, then you will need to provide a dataset so there is something meaningful to use as labels, and be more specific about the coloring schema needed.